# This query to delete the record from while is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I used it as a key id to delete the specific row in while loop, but I don't know where is the problem and give an error.

```
<?php

$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");

if(isset($_POST['deleteId'])){
    $query5 = "DELETE FROM dones WHERE id = '$_POST[deleteId]'"; 
    $result5=mysqli_query($db,$query5);
} 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

    echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';
    echo '<div class="card" style="margin-left:10px; margin- 
            right:10px;">';
    echo '<div class="card-header">';
    echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
    echo '<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    echo  '<button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none; font- 
            family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:18px; " type="button" 
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" 
            aria-controls="collapseOne">';
    echo   $row['title'];
    echo '</button>';
    echo '</h5>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria- 
    labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">';
    echo  '<div class="card-body">';

    // Content Of new banner

    echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;">
            <small>Title</small></h5>';
    echo '<input style="width:290px; margin-left:158px; height:30px; 
            margin-top:-30px;" name="title" type="text" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Title">';
    echo ' <br>';
    echo ' <div class="custom-file" style="height:10px; width:290px; margin- 
                right:1050px; top-padding:20px; float:right;">';
    echo ' <input type="file" name="uploadfile" class="custom-file-input" 
            id="validatedCustomFile">';
    echo ' <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choose 
            file...</label>';
    echo ' </div>';
    echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>File</small> 
            </h5>';
    echo ' <br>';
    echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>Banner 
            Image</small></h5>';
    echo ' <div style="height:130px; width:290px; border-width:1px; border- 
            style:solid; float:right; margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-15px;">';


    $sql = "SELECT image FROM dones where status=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<img src= "images/'.$data['image'].'" style="height:130px; 
            width:290px;">';

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';  
    echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"> 
            <small>Status</small></h5>';
    echo '<select name="status" id="" style="width:290px; float:right; 
            margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-25px;">';
    echo '<option value="1" name="enable">Enable</option>';
    echo '<option value="0" name="disable">Disable</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<button type="submit" name="tbsubmit"  style="margin-left:250px;" 
            class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>';  
    echo '<button type="submit" name="deletesubmit"  style="margin- 
            left:250px;"  class="btn btn-primary"><a href="'? 
            deleteId=$row['id']'">Delete</a></button>'; 
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo  '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}   

?>
```

Delete is the logic for deleting

Actually I used from this logic

and I write inside the delete button at the end I also used instead of keyID in my database just id. and I don't what is the main problem here.

this is the error

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have closed PHP tags, while next line still contain the PHP code

Comment: Your problem is in trying to build this part of the string `<a href="'? 
     deleteId=$row['id']'"` which is inside an `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this link to delete:

```
echo "<button type='submit' name='deletesubmit' style='margin-left:250px;'  class='btn btn-primary'><a href='?deleteId={$row['id']}'>Delete</a></button>";

//and now the if statemant:

if(isset($_GET['deleteId'])){
   $query5 = "DELETE FROM dones WHERE id='{$_GET['deleteId']}'"; 
   $result5=mysqli_query($db,$query5);
}
```

Comment: I mean this link:  echo "<button type='submit' name='deletesubmit' style='margin- left:250px;'  class='btn btn-primary'><a href='?deleteId={$row['id']}'>Delete</a></button>";

Comment: ok, now it doesn't give error so could you check the query but it doesn't delete the record what is the problem

Comment: so like this it is right:if(isset($_GET['deleteId'])){ $query5 = "DELETE FROM dones WHERE id='{$_GET['deleteId']}'"; $result5=mysqli_query($db,$query5); }

Comment: I used the same technic to update the while loop but it doesn't work and there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong quote squence is in your code
try concat the $row['id'] value eg:

```
     echo '<button type="submit" 
            name="deletesubmit"  
            style="margin-left:250px;"  
            class="btn btn-primary">
            <a href="?deleteId='. $row['id']. '">Delete</a></button>';
```

Comment: ok, now it doesn't give error so could you check the query but it doesn't delete the record what is the problem